# How to average graph functions and find the confidence band in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, standard-deviation, graphing, spatstat

I'm using the 'spatstat' package in R and obtained a set of Ripley's K functions (or L functions). I want to find a good way to average out this set of graphs on a single average line, as well as graphing out the standard deviation or confidence interval around this average line.

So far I've tried:

```
env.A <- envelope(A, fun=Lest, correction=c("Ripley"), nsim=99, rank=1, global=TRUE)
Aa <- env.A
avg <- eval.fv((Aa+Bb+Cc+Dd+Ee+Ff+Gg+Hh+Ii+Jj+Kk+Ll+Mm+Nn+Oo+Pp+Qq+Rr+Ss+Tt+Uu+Vv+Ww+Xx)/24)
plot(avg, xlim=c(0,200), . - r ~ r, ylab='', legend='')
```

With this, I got the average line from the data set.

However, I'm now stuck on finding the confidence interval around this average line.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The help file for `envelope` explains how to do this.

```
E <- envelope(A, Lest, correction="Ripley", nsim=100, VARIANCE=TRUE)
plot(E, . - r ~ r)
```

See `help(envelope)` for more explanation.

In this example, the average or middle curve is computed using a theoretical formula, because the simulations are generated from Complete Spatial Randomness, and the theoretical value of the `L` function is known. If you want the middle curve to be determined by the sample averages instead, set `use.theo = FALSE` in the call to `envelope`.

Can I also point out that the bands you get from `envelope` are **not** confidence intervals. A confidence interval would be centred around the estimated L function for the data point pattern `A`. The bands you get from the `envelope` command are centred around the mean value of the simulated curves. They are **significance bands** and their interpretation is related to a statistical significance test. This is also explained in the help file.